# Max +1 with two digits always

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I 'm using this code:

```
// example of my columns: 01
                          02
                          03


select max(panelname) + 1
```

I want my result have always two digits. Lets say that my value is >10 when adding +1 to take this result ex.  from 01 to 02
when value is < 10  when adding +1 to take this result ex.from 23 to 24

Comment: What's the datatype of `panelname`, string or numeric? If it's the former it's the wrong type, if it's the latter it's a client fomatting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN max(panelname) + 1 < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), max(panelname) + 1)
```